# Quarkus 3.0 upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, quarkus

I try to upgrade quarkus from version 2.16.7 to 3.0.3. So far without success.

First I tried to upgrade quarkus manually with the [migration guide](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-3.0).
When I tried to start quarkus I did not get any error messages. But every endpoint from quarkus was not reachable anymore. At the end you can find my pom.xml file.

Secondly I tried to upgrade quarkus with the automtic quarkus cli command:

```
quarkus update --stream=3.0
```

But then I get the following error message:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------< at.tanzauswertung.portal-backend:portal-backend >-----------
[INFO] Building portal-backend 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:3.0.3.Final:update (default-cli) @ portal-backend ---
[WARNING] quarkus:update goal is experimental, its options and output might change in future versions
[ERROR] The project does not import any Quarkus platform BOM
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.669 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-14T21:25:34+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.0.3.Final:update (default-cli) on project portal-backend: The command did not succeed. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.0.3.Final:update (default-cli) on project portal-backend: The command did not succeed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: The command did not succeed.
    at io.quarkus.maven.UpdateMojo.processProjectState (UpdateMojo.java:131)
    at io.quarkus.maven.QuarkusProjectStateMojoBase.doExecute (QuarkusProjectStateMojoBase.java:59)
    at io.quarkus.maven.QuarkusProjectMojoBase.execute (QuarkusProjectMojoBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>at.tanzauswertung.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>portal-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>at.tanzauswertung.portal-backend</groupId>
    <artifactId>portal-backend</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <webapp.dependency.phase>prepare-package</webapp.dependency.phase>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.1.0</surefire-plugin.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.26</lombok.version>
        <keycloak.version>20.0.3</keycloak.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.17.6</testcontainers.version>
        <quarkus.version>3.0.3.Final</quarkus.version>
        <version.apache-poi>5.2.2</version.apache-poi>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-universe-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>at.tanzauswertung.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>pea-portal-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>castor-xml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.olap4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>olap4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
                    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
                    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${version.apache-poi}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${version.apache-poi}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-mailer</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-narayana-jta</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-scheduler</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-agroal</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-undertow</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-keycloak-authorization</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-oidc</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-test-h2</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dasniko</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers-keycloak</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-flyway</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/META-INF/resources/portal
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/portal-webapp/build/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>skipFrontendBuild</id>
            <properties>
                <surefire-plugin.version>${surefire-plugin.version}</surefire-plugin.version>
                <webapp.dependency.phase>none</webapp.dependency.phase>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Quarkus tooling is looking for the Quarkus BOM and is not able to find it. It seems your project is using the legacy BOM definition.

My recommendation would be to generate a blank project through [code.quarkus.io](https://code.quarkus.io/?S=io.quarkus.platform%3A2.16) using 2.16 stream. Compare the pom.xml to yours, you should have something like this:

```xml
 <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.16.7.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
...
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
```

Then retry updating using the command you specified and let me know :)

Comment: Could you validate my answer and create another question? (and add a link from this one)